# Image content disappearing for a Label inside a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, image, label

I have a ListBox containing multiple items. The DataTemplate for the items looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileItem}">
   <Grid Name="FileItemGrid">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="28"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       <Label Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Width="24">
         <Label.Style>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
             <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
             <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InProgress}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Waiting}"/>
               </DataTrigger>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converted}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Converted}"/>
               </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>
         </Label.Style>
       </Label>
     </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Basically I want to show an image to the right on the ListBoxItem showing the current processing status.  At the beginning we show nothing, and when the processing for an item starts the code behind sets "InProgress" for the item. When the item is finished it sets "Converted" to true, and "InProgress" back to false. The referenced StaticResources Waiting and Converted are simply Images.

```
<Image x:Key="Waiting" Source="Images/Waiting.png"></Image>
```

However there is a very strange problem. As the code behind progresses through the list, the images start disappearing. The previously converted item loses its image as soon as the next item in the list switches icon.

[image]

I know the code behind is working properly, because if instead of images I switch to simple text everything is fine.

```
<Setter Property="Content" Value="Waiting..."/>
```

[image]

One more interesting bit of information. When inspecting the visual tree using Snoop, when the image is not shown there is definitely something wrong with the ContentPresenter. It looks like there is nothing in it - as compared to one which is working.

[image]

Even though the Content field does claim there is an image in there:

[image]

Comment: Before anyone suggests it, I tried using a converter instead, and yes that does work.  But I would really like to know why using static resource in a data trigger doesn't

Comment: Perhaps some good night reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xshared-attribute

Comment: Better than setting `x:Shared"  would be not to use UIElement resources at all. Instead of a Label, use an Image element and set its Source property to different BitmapImage resources.

Comment: I guess that's why the converter approach works. That's excellent everyone. I learned something new. Although if you were using Geometry, Paths, or vector graphics I guess x:Shared would still be the correct approach.